# Ng bootstrap does not install on angular 13

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

When I update angular 12 to 13, "ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" command does not work & gives me an error like this,

[image]

So how to solve this error? thanks

Answer (score 1):

run following command first

`npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`

then install ng-bootstrap

`npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

this did work for me.

Comment: thanks for this, It's working now

Answer (score 0):

ng-bootstrap doesn't support Angular 13 so far: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#dependencies

Answer (score 0):

ng-bootstrap currently doesn’t support Angular 13, but an issue has already been raised and you can follow along here: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/4178

Comment: @VarshilDoshi no problem, please accept this as the answer if it helped you.